# Not able to Configure Scroll Area in Pyqt5 Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qscrollarea

[image: My Application]

[Complete Code](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AusYy6F7np9zh7pyXC6SSTJJ8_IXTg?e=B3TQ5P)

I am expecting a scroll bar should get auto populate so that user can see the rest of the item.

in that highlighted area I tried

1. created one widget
2. added one Scroll Area under that widget
3. add a from lay out under Scroll Area
4. adding items to that from layout.

but the scroll area is not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName('MainWindow')
        MainWindow.resize(817, 588)
        sizePolicy = \
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                                  QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName('centralwidget')
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = \
            QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 761,
                60))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName('verticalLayoutWidget')
        self.verticalLayout = \
            QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName('verticalLayout')
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName('gridLayout')
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName('label')
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(
            self.label,
            0,
            0,
            1,
            1,
            QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft,
            )
        self.searchString = \
            QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.searchString.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(673, 16777215))
        self.searchString.setObjectName('searchString')
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.searchString, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.submit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.submit.setObjectName('submit')
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.submit, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.errorLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.errorLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 751, 16))
        self.errorLabel.setText('')
        self.errorLabel.setObjectName('errorLabel')
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 140, 361, 151))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName('groupBox')
        self.serverList = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.serverList.setEnabled(True)
        self.serverList.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 331, 121))
        self.serverList.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.serverList.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Fixed)
        self.serverList.setObjectName('serverList')
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.serverList.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.serverList.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.serverList.addItem(item)
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 140, 361, 151))
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName('groupBox_2')
        self.autoDownload = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.groupBox_2)
        self.autoDownload.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 121, 20))
        self.autoDownload.setObjectName('autoDownload')
        self.specificFileFlag = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.groupBox_2)
        self.specificFileFlag.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 171, 20))
        self.specificFileFlag.setObjectName('specificFileFlag')
        self.downloadSelected = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.downloadSelected.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 97, 141, 31))
        self.downloadSelected.setObjectName('downloadSelected')
        self.searchArchive = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.groupBox_2)
        self.searchArchive.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 30, 141, 20))
        self.searchArchive.setObjectName('searchArchive')
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.groupBox_2)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 60, 191, 21))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName('checkBox')
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 540, 161, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName('label_2')
        self.selectedServer = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.selectedServer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 751, 21))
        self.selectedServer.setText('')
        self.selectedServer.setObjectName('selectedServer')
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 300, 761, 241))
        self.widget.setObjectName('widget')
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 6, 731, 221))


        self.scrollArea.setObjectName('scrollArea')
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0,
                729, 219))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName('scrollAreaWidgetContents'
                )
        self.formLayoutWidget = \
            QtWidgets.QWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 1, 731, 221))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName('formLayoutWidget')
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(9, 9, 9, 9)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName('formLayout')
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName('checkBox_2')
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole,
                                  self.checkBox_2)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.progressBar.setProperty('value', 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName('progressBar')
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole,
                                  self.progressBar)
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName('checkBox_3')
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole,
                                  self.checkBox_3)
        self.progressBar_2 = \
            QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.progressBar_2.setProperty('value', 24)
        self.progressBar_2.setObjectName('progressBar_2')
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole,
                                  self.progressBar_2)
        self.checkBox_4 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_4.setObjectName('checkBox_4')
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole,
                                  self.checkBox_4)
        self.progressBar_3 = \
            QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.progressBar_3.setProperty('value', 24)
        self.progressBar_3.setObjectName('progressBar_3')
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole,
                                  self.progressBar_3)
        self.checkBox_5 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_5.setObjectName('checkBox_5')
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole,
                                  self.checkBox_5)
        self.progressBar_4 = \
            QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.progressBar_4.setProperty('value', 24)
        self.progressBar_4.setObjectName('progressBar_4')
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole,
                                  self.progressBar_4)
        count = 6
        c = 0
        checkBox = []
        while count < 10:
            checkBox.append(QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.formLayoutWidget))
            checkBox[c].setObjectName('checkBox_' + str(c))
            checkBox[c].setText('test_' + str(c))

            
            self.formLayout.setWidget(count,
                    QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, checkBox[c])

            
            self.formLayout.setWidget(count,
                    QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole,
                    QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.formLayoutWidget))
            count = count + 1
            c = c + 1
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName('statusbar')
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate('MainWindow', 'MainWindow'
                                  ))
        self.label.setText(_translate('MainWindow',
                           '<html><head/><body><p><span style=" font-weight:600; color:#000000;">Search String</span><span style=" font-weight:600; color:#ff0000;">*</span></p></body></html>'
                           ))
        self.submit.setText(_translate('MainWindow', 'Search'))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate('MainWindow', 'Server List'))
        __sortingEnabled = self.serverList.isSortingEnabled()
        self.serverList.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.serverList.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate('MainWindow', 'TVOL'))
        item = self.serverList.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate('MainWindow', 'QA2'))
        item = self.serverList.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate('MainWindow', 'CVOL'))
        self.serverList.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate('MainWindow',
                                 'Other Configuration'))
        self.autoDownload.setToolTip(_translate('MainWindow',
                '<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>'))
        self.autoDownload.setText(_translate('MainWindow',
                                  'Auto Download'))
        self.specificFileFlag.setToolTip(_translate('MainWindow',
                '<html><head/><body><p>write the file name in &quot;Search String&quot; and Click on Search Button</p></body></html>'
                ))
        self.specificFileFlag.setText(_translate('MainWindow',
                'Download Specific file'))
        self.downloadSelected.setText(_translate('MainWindow',
                'Download Selected'))
        self.searchArchive.setText(_translate('MainWindow',
                                   'Search in Archive'))
        self.checkBox.setToolTip(_translate('MainWindow',
                                 '<html><head/><body><p>This option will try to compress the file in server before downloading</p></body></html>'
                                 ))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate('MainWindow',
                              'Compress Before Download'))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate('MainWindow',
                             '<html><head/><body><p><span style=" color:#969696;">Created by - Sudipto Khan</span></p></body></html>'
                             ))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate('MainWindow', 'CheckBox'))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate('MainWindow', 'CheckBox'))
        self.checkBox_4.setText(_translate('MainWindow', 'CheckBox'))
        self.checkBox_5.setText(_translate('MainWindow', 'CheckBox'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't understand you, I do observe the scrollbar

Comment: please check the snap that i shared. no scroll bar showing

Comment: I have used the MRE (I will not use the link code) and I do not see any problem: https://i.imgur.com/L5oCYmX.png

Comment: hi ,i am able to solve that issue. thanks :)